# Deploy Silverlight With Local IIS - Advisable?

Tags: silverlight, iis, deployment, local

I'm in the process of reengineering a desktop application to a Silverlight4-WCF client-server architecture.  Apparently, some (not all) of our clients have very limited resources or dysfunctional relationships with their I/T support staff.  Consequently, I've been asked to come up with a solution that would enable these clients to install the new SL app on a local desktop, possibly running IIS locally.  Will probably wrap all this up in a installer to make deployment super easy.

While I don't endorse the idea of running IIS locally on each user's desktop, my thinking is that it will probably work.  The biggest problem I envision is security -- the server code and configuration would be available locally.  Still, I'm looking for input from the wider developer community because I'm uncomfortable by the proposal.  What kind of hell and difficulties do you envision, or can this work with minimal fuss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IIS locally may be more trouble than it's worth. Most configuration/maintenance tasks require the user to have Administrator access on the computer. Securing it is a bitch. Making sure its configuration doesn't drift and remains working as you release new versions is even more so. Moreover, it's not included in all Windows editions, e.g. Windows 7 Home edition. I recommend trying to roll with [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/) as an embedded HTTP server instead.

As for code security - if you can't trust your clients' IT to look after deployment and security, or they can't/don't want to, you could host the server-side yourself and bill your customers for it, i.e. SaaS.

Just my 2 cents.

EDIT:
Oh, yeah. If you're concerned about trade secret theft, e.g. reverse engineering of your server code, just run it through an obfuscator, e.g. SmartAssembly. That'll give you an edge. As for IP theft, e.g. piracy, use could use some online license checking scheme - it won't compromise client privacy, and it'll deter copying.

Comment: Funny thing is we offer a hosted solution option.  Apparently, some clients do not have access to fast Internet connections or perhaps due to concerns for ultra-privacy prefer a local solution.  I was thinking of using IIS Express, but didn't consider using it as an embedded HTTP Server.  Interesting suggestion, thanks.